# Remove Profile Centre/Unsubscribe Links from Marketing Cloud Transactional Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

While sending an email using the 'Default Transactional' Send Classification, the Standard Marketing Cloud Footer is showing up. See the attachment below:

[image]

Shouldn't this footer only appear in 'Commericial' type Send Classifications? Thanks!

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted, so others can easily see this has been answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can deactivate the default headers and footers under Administration -> Account Settings -> Edit in the Headers and Footers section. Here you have the following options

- System Default
- Custom
- None

If you don't see these you need to reach out to the salesforce marketing cloud support and ask for "standard header/footer deactivation". If you want to use other than the default profile an preference center and unsubscribe links as well, you also have to ask for "email validation rule deactivation".

Comment: Email Validation rule only applies to commercial emails. As long you as you set up a Send Classification you can both: 1. Set the header / footer on your Delivery Profile 2. Set the email to transactional so that it doesn't check for the unsubscribe links. This way you can keep the check in place for commercial emails, and not mess with account default settings.

Answer (score 0):

According to Spam law, all commercial emails should have an unsubscribe link. And this is mandatory for almost every email service provider.

Commercial email is based on your content, which means:

1. Cold emails
2. Opt-in marketing emails
3. Transactional emails

are all considered commercial and should have an unsubscribe link.

Related link: https://customer.io/blog/Send-email-without-unsubscribe-link-cold.html

Comment: Did you read the link you provided? It even states, "3. Do transactional emails need an unsubscribe link? Nope, transactional emails don’t need an unsubscribe link."